# Redirecting output in rc.local not working

Tags: command-line, bash

In my `rc.local`folder, I've added this command. '

```
/home/rootadmin/.virtualenvs/data_collection/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/data_collection_project.ini &>> /etc/uwsgi/uwsgioutput.txt
```

I thought the `&>> /etc/uwsgi/uwsgioutput.txt` would redirect all output from this command to `/etc/uwsgi/uwsgioutput.txt`. Instead, if I run `sudo service rc.local start`, all output will be visible in that shell. If i open another shell, no output will be visible. In both cases, nothing is written to `/etc/uwsgi/uwsgioutput.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&>>` is a [bashism](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism) - it won't be understood by the `dash` shell that is (AFAIK) still the default for `/etc/rc.local` (rather, it will understand it as `&` followed by `>>` i.e. background the command and then append nothing to the file).

You will need to change your command to use the POSIX form of the redirection i.e. `cmd >> outfile 2>&1`

```
/home/rootadmin/.virtualenvs/data_collection/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/sites/data_collection_project.ini >> /etc/uwsgi/uwsgioutput.txt 2>&1
```